# OpenMPI MCA parameters does not have an effect

Tags: linux, tcp, centos, mpi

I am trying to setup some of the mca parameters for an mpi execution,
The command I am trying to run is:

```
 mpirun --mca btl_base_verbose 30 --mca btl_tcp_if_include eth1 -nolocal -pernode -machinefile .hostlist -np 3 ./a.out
```

But either btl_base_verbose and btl_tcp_if_include does not produce any effect. 
Any ideas? Thanks!

Centos 5 x86_64, OpenMPI 1.4.3..

```
    ldd /opt/mpi/gcc/openmpi-1.4.3/bin/mpirun
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff765fd000)
    libopen-rte.so.0 => /opt/mpi/gcc/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libopen-rte.so.0 (0x00002b6046a1a000)
    libtorque.so.2 => /opt/pbs/lib/libtorque.so.2 (0x00002b6046c9e000)
    libopen-pal.so.0 => /opt/mpi/gcc/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libopen-pal.so.0 (0x00002b6046ef6000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00000037e4e00000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00000037ee000000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00000037f2000000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00000037e5200000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00000037e5a00000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00000037e4a00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000037e4600000)
```

Comment: This makes little sense. At least setting `btl_base_verbose` to 30 should produce lots of output from the BTL framework. Are you sure that `mpirun` really comes from Open MPI and there is no other MPI implementation installed that might interfere?

Comment: Thats possible since i have mpich installed too. But according to Ompi_info mpirun and mpi-selector i have selected as default ompi. I wonder if that is the case how to solve the conflicts. Thanks

Comment: Use `ldd` to check which library the executable is linked against. If necessary use `strings /path/to/mpi/library.so` to make sure that it is indeed Open MPI. Also `mpicc --showme:version` should output the Open MPI version.

Comment: Still not working, I edit my posted adding the output of ldd

Comment: What I meant was that you should use `ldd` on the `a.out` executable, not on `mpirun`.

Comment: I finally solve it. As you said I didnt link the executable against the libraries well. Thanks